# How to use a usb-drive / pendrive?

Tags: linux, usb-drive

When pluging the pendrive, a message shows:

```
[   67.317741] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[   67.317741] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I don't mind having that message, because that's just the way the media is formatted, and I find it good that the system is reminding this to me, but why after the message shows the CLI stays <s>inside a process</s> there? Should I just press `ctrl + c` <s>to terminate the process</s>?

How to access the media and copy files from and towards it?

Finally how to remove the media safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLI does not stay 'inside a process'.  That kernel messages was displayed on your terminal *independent* of the shell.  You are in effect still at the previous shell prompt; just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> if you want to move to the next line.

---

To access data on the drive, you will probably want to [mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) the drive, for example

```
mount /dev/sdb /mnt
```

to view the drive under `/mnt`.  When done using the drive, you would ensure no processes were accessing the drive, and then

```
umount /dev/sdb
```

These commands will probably need to be run with superuser privilege (`sudo`).  You may also need to specify other options; check the man page.

Comment: After unmounting, you might also want to do a `echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/delete` for a maximally safe removal. That command effectively tells the kernel "prepare for hot-unplugging of block device `sdb`."